# Executing scheme code

Tags: printing, scheme, lisp

I'm completely new to all functional programming dialects, and I have an assignment due based on "Scheme/Lisp". For the this program I want to get more familiar with the `car` and `cdr` functions by experimenting. Is there an environment where I can play around with using `car` and `cdr` on a list like `(id = id - const)`. So that I can get a better idea of how I want to implement my parser that I have to build? Perhaps there is a method similar to print in languages like java or c?

Comment: Both C and Java (and pretty much most modern languages) are Algol dialects. Thus they resemble each other. Eg. if you know Java it's very easy to learn perl. It's the same with LISP. If you know one lisp language it's simple to learn another. It's not simple to transfer Algol knowledge into Lisp knowledge since it's not a new dialect but a new language. `(id = id - const)` looks like a infix assignment in Algol. In Scheme you can do `(set! id (- id const))` but i most cases you should refrain from mutation and use recursion instead. You display results with the procedure `display`.

Answer (score 2):

You can download DrRacket here:  http://download.racket-lang.org/

DrRacket allows you to edit and run programs easily.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an environment to play around with Lisp in?
Just on the chance it may broaden your horizon, you might want to start using the editor GNU Emacs which is extendable and programmable - in Lisp!
(It's the dialect elisp which resembles the old school dialect Maclisp.)

GNU Emacs: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Scheme interpreter that runs in your browser:

http://repl.it/languages/Scheme